# Regex issues in javascript?

Tags: javascript, regex

```
var string1 = "code-abcd-1234";
var string2 = "abcd-1234-code";
var regexp = /(?:(\w{4})-(\d{4})|(?<=code-)|(?=-code)){2}/;
console.log(string1.match(regexp), string2.match(regexp));
```

console result:

```
["abcd-1234", "abcd", "1234"]
["abcd-1234", undefined, undefined]
```

Why the groups (...) not working in string2?

Comment: No need to wonder, `{2}` applied to a non-capturing group containing capturing groups made it a repeated capturing group, and the group values are re-initialized at each iteration. This would work in PHP  or [Python](https://ideone.com/8sx9xh), but not in JavaScript.

Comment: And the second time the pattern matches, only `(?=-code)` matches but not `(\w{4})-(\d{4})`.